# What should I do if I've attracted a bunch of vultures?

Tags: diablo-iii

In act 2 of Diablo III there are vulture-like monsters that circle in the air around the hero until they spot a "weakness", and then they swoop down to attack. What is the definition of "weakness", and is there anything I can do to force them down earlier, when I'm not at a disadvantage?

Comment: Run away, they just want your money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the "moment of weakness" is when one of the following applies:

- You have less than maximum health.
- You have encountered another monster pack and they are attacking you or you are attacking them.

If you have some way of damaging yourself in a controlled setting - e.g. by activating a weak trap - it might be a relatively safe way of getting them down.

However, **they also swoop down if you just let some time pass**, so if you have the patience and don't want to be attacked at a disadvantage, just wait it out.